# Essential Ideals and Socle of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$ (commutative ring with unity) such that $I$ intersects every ideal non-trivially. We call such ideal essential. Likewise in any category we have a notion of essential subobjects.

I'm trying to prove that intersection of all essential ideals is the sum of minimal ideals in R. (The sum of minimal ideals are called Socle. We denote socle as $\mathrm{Soc}(R)$.)

Here's what I've been working on:

Suppose $\{A_α: α∈∧\}$ is the collection of all minimal ideals. Then for any essential ideal $E$ of $R$, $A_α∩E=A_α$ so $A_α⊂ E ∀α∈ ∧$. Therefore $∑A_α⊂ E$ for every essential ideal $E$. So $∑A_α$ is contained in the intersection.

Comment: At present your question is only slightly more than a problem statement.  It should be obvious the socle is contained in the intersection of essentials.  How about you show that and then make a step towards showing the other containment, so people know you are engaged with the question and not just fishing for answers?

Comment: I added the obvious part. For the other part I'm trying use this lemma: B be any ideal of R then B \bigoplus Ann(B) is an essential ideal.

Comment: That lemma is not true as stated, so I do not think it will be helpful here. Can you translate the last line of the post so we know it accurately in english?

Comment: A proof is outlined here for modules. https://pages.uoregon.edu/anderson/rings/LECTURE8.PDF

Comment: Point of fact: I cast my vote before your edit, and it would have been one of the four other votes that closed it. That said, I do not understand why they would add close votes given the edit. Finally, there is no reason to react so negatively to a closure: they are intended to be reversed when the question is improved, as I believe it has in this case.

Comment: Since I think your question is just fine now, I've cast a reopen vote. If this happens again then I would recommend just politely making a case for reopening rather than issuing a possibly incorrect accusation to someone helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses a useful lemma:

> If $N$ is a submodule of $M$, then there exists a submodule $C$ of $M$ such that $N\oplus C$ is essential in $M$.

It just relies on a routine Zorn's lemma argument.

Let $E$ denote the intersection of essential submodules and $S$ denote the socle.  We can show $E$ is a semisimple module using that lemma, establishing the "hard" containment $E\subseteq S$.

Let $N$ be any submodule of $E$, and find $C$ such that $N\oplus C$ is essential in $M$. By definition $E\subseteq N\oplus C$, and further by modularity of the lattice of submodules,

$$
E=E\cap (N\oplus C) = N\oplus (E\cap C)
$$
Therefore every submodule of $E$ is a summand of $E$, establishing that $E$ is a semisimple module, and therefore must be contained in the socle.